# How to simultaneously query two APIs in Python?

Tags: python, asynchronous, multiprocessing

Using web.py, I'm building a website in which I display search results from two third party websites through their public API. Unfortunately, for the APIs to send back the result takes about 4 seconds. If I query the second API only after I received the answer from the first, this obviously takes me about 8 seconds, which is way too long. To bring this down I want to send the requests to the APIs simultaneously and simply continue as soon as I received an answer from both the APIs.

My problem is now: how to do this?

I've never worked with parallel computing, but I've heard of multiprocessing and threading. I don't really know what the difference or advantages of each are. I also know that for example C++ is able to do parallel computations. It could therefore also be an option to write the part that queries the APIs in C++ (I'm a beginner in C++, but I think I'd manage). Finally, there could of course be options that I am totally overlooking. Maybe web.py has some options to do this, or maybe there are Python modules which are specifically made to do this?

Since only researching and understanding all of these options would take me quite a lot of time, I thought I'd ask you guys here for some tips.

So which one do you think I should go for? And most importantly: why? All tips are welcome!

Comment: Are you sure you need to send then simultaneously? Sounds more like you just want to be able to send them asynchronously.
Also please consider updating your tags appropriately, this seems only barely related to C++, and is not related to multiprocessing.  Basic threading and or async will get the job done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want an *asynchronous* HTTP request library. Examples of this would be [`gevent`](http://www.gevent.org/), or [`grequests`](https://github.com/kennethreitz/grequests).

Alternatively, you could use Python's built-in [`threading`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html) module to run synchronous requests in multiple threads.

Either way, no need to go to another language.

Comment: I just had a quick look at grequests and that indeed looks good. But would you know if I can also send headers with it (I need to send some Authorization headers). I can't find anything about it..

Comment: Yes, you can. `grequests` is simply an asynchronous wrapper around `requests`, which supports sending headers - http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#custom-headers . Anything that `requests` can do, `grequests` also can.

Comment: Thanks for that! Works like a charm! I just had some trouble installing grequests. The cause of this was that I needed to install libevent-dev (maybe interesting for future readers).. Cheers!